# Declare @State variable inside HStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create a @State variable for each item on a list and inside a HStack, but when i try to create a variable inside a view i'm getting an error

**The error:**

```
Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'
```

**The variable:**

```
@State var imageName: String = "uncheckedIcon"
```

Comment: You can not create var inside the HStack or VStack you have to create new struct view and use it inside the HStack

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve? Why don't you just declare the property on the View itself, why are you trying to declare it inside the `HStack`? You can only use `@State` (and property wrappers in general) on properties of types, you cannot use them on local variables.

Comment: @DávidPásztor i just want to chage the image of an `Image()` view when the user click an item inside the list (i don't want to change the image for all items inside the list)

Comment: Just separate that view part into subview and use state there.

Comment: @Asperi can you please explain what did you mean or just post an Answer? :-) (thanks for your time)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to declare variables inside any view, you should declare it inside the struct and then call it inside your view. Also to make it change for each view in a List, you can create another struct view and it would be something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ListItemView()
            ListItemView()
            ListItemView()
            ListItemView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListItemView: View {
    @State var showText = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showText {
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()
            } else {
                Text("Changed text")
                    .padding()
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            showText.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i just want to chage the image of an Image() view when the user click an item inside the list (i don't want to change the image for all items inside the list)

Comment: Can you show some of your code? maybe the part that shows how do you populate the list

Comment: I fixed the problem by creating another struct with the list item view and i put there the State variable. If you want you can edit your answer to accept it :-)

Comment: @GSepetadelis That was a nice solution, I edited to help others with the same needs. ;)

Comment: Good job you are the best ;-)